# Как парсить "сложную" URL строку, как достать значения из URL?

Tags: javascript

Есть такой код:

```
let parsedUrl = new URL("https://streamguard.cc/serial/412c6a4100be1a0f41a4c57b00c2d57d/iframe?season=1&nocontrols=1&episode=366?origin=yummyanime.com"); // ?...?...
console.log(parsedUrl.searchParams.get("episode") ); // wparam="366?origin=yummyanime.com" TODO: param="366"
```

URL получаю через window.location.href , а вверху URL в качестве примера.

*Как обойтись без метода split?*

`parsedUrl.searchParams.get("episode").split("?"); // Array [ "366", "origin=yummyanime.com" ];`

Я думаю что не правильно будет так разбивать и наверное нужно разделить строки до метода **get**. В идеале бы результат такого "parsed URL" записывался бы в массив.

`// Array [ "season=1&nocontrols=1&episode=366", "origin=yummyanime.com" ]`

**Поддержка для браузеров MS не нужна.**

Спустя некоторое время, написал вот такое:

```
let parsedUrl = new URL(window.location.href);
parsedUrl.href.split("?").map(function(echo){
    return new URLSearchParams(echo).get("episode");
});//Array [ null, "366", null ]
```

Пойдет такое решение?
Может есть более элегантное и понятное решение?
За стиль извиняюсь бывший с++'шник :)
Мне только бы **на чистом JS**, если можно и output равен "s=1&e=366".

При url.match(/episode=(\d+)/)[1] нужно будет воспользоваться конструкцией **try..catch**.

---

Сгодиться пара `//Array["1","366"]` в итоге планируется запись в БД. Или можно получить output строкой формата "s="+data+"&e="+data ("s=1&e=366").

Comment: В итоге так и не понятно, что вы хотите получить. Данные из get? разделенные как ключ значение или парами в массиве или еще что.. output какой?

Comment: ничего не понятно, но кажется надо найти эпизод ... с таким урлом наверное проще изобразить что-то типа url.match(/episode=(\d+)/)[1]

Comment: Сообщения надо править со своего аккаунта, а не с анонимного.

Comment: Если вам нужно распарсить get, то window.location.search в помощь. И почему "использовать split" неправильно?

Comment: [Ссылка тырк](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646851/split-and-parse-window-location-hash) Выбираешь где больше голосов, потом Ctrl + С